# python assignment order in expression

Tags: python

```
# class defined here.
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

# A function here.
def list_init(lst):
    if not lst:
        return None

    root = ListNode(lst[0])
    temp = root
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        temp.next = ListNode(lst[i]) #
        temp = temp.next # these two lines I want to simplify
    return root
```

when I simplify the two lines as

```
temp = temp.next = ListNode(lst[i])
```

Thing's going wrong and the root.next is None.

What's the difference between these two way of assignment expression?

I think they are the same, but the result is not the same.

However, I change the statement into

```
temp.next = temp = ListNode(lst[i])
```

the result is correct, confused.

Comment: Even if it was the same, why would you even do that? It's not clear to me whether temp.next gets set first, or temp get set first. You shouldn't rely on people knowing the particularity of how the languages chooses to implement stuff like this.

Comment: I think you are right. But I think the assignment of value is from the right to the left, so the temp.next gets first, IMO.

Comment: I think I work it out: temp = temp.next = ListNode(lst[i]) is equal to temp = ListNode(lst[i]), temp.next = ListNode(lst[i]). That's why I get the wrong ans. It's different with C. In python, it's from left.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment statement binds all names to the same object on the RHS. Use **tuple unpacking** if you want to handle multiple objects properly.

```
temp, temp.next = temp.next, ListNode(lst[i])
```

Comment: I tried your code, still wrong with: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next', meaning root.next is still None.

Comment: @Izana: That's because your initial goal was impossible in the first place. Those two assignments *must* occur in that order.

Comment: May you explain what is RHS? Thx. From the way of tuple unpacking, it's impossible. But when I change the order into temp.next = temp = ListNode(lst[i]), the result is right. It's more confusing.

Comment: And when you run the first unsimplified code, the temp and temp.next are all binds to the same obj ListNode(lst[i]). It is equal to the "binds all names to the same object on the RHS", I think.

Comment: I think u r right, and I think find out what's wrong in there. The expression first binds the temp with ListNode(lst[i]), so the value of temp is changed, and the temp of temp.next is the updated temp instead of the old temp value.